# r-base-core can't be configured

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, dpkg, r

When trying to install R on Ubuntu 16.04 xenial, I'm stuck because `r-base-core` can't be configured. I'm using the [common manual](https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-install-r-on-linux-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus/). After the failed installation and trying to manually configure `r-base-core` the console basically looks like this:

```
~$ sudo dpkg --configure r-base-core
   Setting up r-base-core (3.3.2-1xenial0) ...
   dpkg: error processing package r-base-core (--configure):
    subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit      
    status 10
   Errors were encountered while processing:
   r-base-core
```

The post-installation script `r-base-core.postinst` 
 in `/var/lib/dpkg/info` contains the following:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
#
# postinst script for the Debian GNU/Linux r-base-core package
# This version originally written by Douglas Bates <bates@stat.wisc.edu>
# and now written and maintained by Dirk Eddelbuettel <edd@debian.org>

set -e

# Automatically added by dh_installdeb
dpkg-maintscript-helper mv_conffile /etc/bash_completion.d/R /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/R -- "$@"
# End automatically added section



case "$1" in
  configure)
    # edd 19 Jun 2004   deal with papersize 
    # edd 22 Jun 2004   make that conditional on paperconf
    # edd 25 Oct 2006   rewritten for R 2.4.0 and R_PAPERSIZE_USER
    # edd 21 Jun 2008   rewritten for R 2.7.1 and ucf input 
    # edd 23 Feb 2013   trying to avoid md5sum issues with help from Andy Beckman
    # edd 26 Feb 2013   correct mode of temp. Renviron file with help from Don Armstrong
    tmpRenviron=$(mktemp)
    chmod 0644 "$tmpRenviron"
    cat /usr/lib/R/etc/Renviron.ucf > "$tmpRenviron"
    #if [ -x /usr/bin/paperconf ]; then
        ## get the value we want from Debian's paperconf utility
        papersize=`paperconf`
    ## have perl subst. second expression with $papersize for first
    ## uses the x mod. and curlies to denote the usual s|1st|2nd|
    perl -p -i -e "s{^R_PAPERSIZE_USER=\\$\{R_PAPERSIZE\}}
        {R_PAPERSIZE_USER=\\$\{R_PAPERSIZE-'$papersize'\}}x" "$tmpRenviron"
    #fi
    # edd 21 Jun 2008  whether or not Renviron was modified, ucf will handle it, 
    #                  so tell ucf that file Renviron.ucf is the source for 
    #                  conffile in /etc and register it
    ucf "$tmpRenviron" /etc/R/Renviron
    ucfr r-base-core /etc/R/Renviron
    rm -f "$tmpRenviron"
    #
    #if [ -x /usr/bin/update-menus ]; then
    #  update-menus 
    #fi

    # edd 03 Apr 2003  cf Section 10.1.2 of Debian Policy
    if [ ! -e /usr/local/lib/R ]; then
      if mkdir /usr/local/lib/R 2>/dev/null; then
    chown root:staff /usr/local/lib/R
    chmod 2775 /usr/local/lib/R
      fi
    fi
    if [ ! -e /usr/local/lib/R/site-library ]; then
      if mkdir /usr/local/lib/R/site-library 2>/dev/null; then
    chown root:staff /usr/local/lib/R/site-library
    chmod 2775 /usr/local/lib/R/site-library
      fi
    fi

    #if [ -x /usr/bin/mktexlsr ]; then
    #  mktexlsr /usr/share/texmf
    #fi
    ;;
  abort-upgrade|abort-remove|abort-deconfigure)
    ;;
  *)
    echo "postinst called with unknown argument \`$1'" >&2
    ;;
esac
```

I already tried removing the postinstallation script so the configuration above runs without error and in fact r-base can then be installed. However when typing `R` in the console, this is what the console looks like:

```
cannot find system Renviron

R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31) -- "Sincere Pumpkin Patch"
Copyright (C) 2016 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'utils', details:
  call: options(op.utils[toset])
  error: invalid value for 'editor'
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'utils', details:
  call: options(op.utils[toset])
  error: invalid value for 'editor'
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘utils’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
During startup - Warning message:
package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found
```

Setting the environment variable like so doesn't change a thing:

```
export R_HOME=/usr/lib/R/
```

The content of the R installation folder is:

```
~$ ls -l /etc/R
total 40
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  793 Nov  1 11:45 ldpaths
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  784 Apr 24  2016 ldpaths.dpkg-old
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6304 Nov  1 11:45 Makeconf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6354 Apr 24  2016 Makeconf.dpkg-old
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  608 Apr 24  2016 Renviron.site
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1161 Nov  1 11:45 repositories
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1424 Apr 24  2016 repositories.dpkg-old
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  792 Apr 24  2016 Rprofile.site
```

Apparently the postinstallation script fails when ucf is supposed to do something. When adding the `-x` argument to the postinstallation script:

```
Setting up r-base-core (3.3.2-1xenial0) ...
+ dpkg-maintscript-helper mv_conffile /etc/bash_completion.d/R /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/R -- configure 
+ mktemp
+ tmpRenviron=/tmp/tmp.MANJybxXxQ
+ chmod 0644 /tmp/tmp.MANJybxXxQ
+ cat /usr/lib/R/etc/Renviron.ucf
+ paperconf
+ papersize=a4
+ perl -p -i -e s{^R_PAPERSIZE_USER=\$\{R_PAPERSIZE\}}
        {R_PAPERSIZE_USER=\$\{R_PAPERSIZE-'a4'\}}x /tmp/tmp.MANJybxXxQ
+ ucf /tmp/tmp.MANJybxXxQ /etc/R/Renviron
dpkg: error processing package r-base-core (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
```

Based on other posts I found online regarding ucf problems in postinstallation scripts, I added debug level 3 to the ucf-line in the posinstallation script. This is what the console looks like now:

```
+ dpkg-maintscript-helper mv_conffile /etc/bash_completion.d/R /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/R -- configure 
+ mktemp
+ tmpRenviron=/tmp/tmp.LsP3FSBIRI
+ chmod 0644 /tmp/tmp.LsP3FSBIRI
+ cat /usr/lib/R/etc/Renviron.ucf
+ paperconf
+ papersize=a4
+ perl -p -i -e s{^R_PAPERSIZE_USER=\$\{R_PAPERSIZE\}}
        {R_PAPERSIZE_USER=\$\{R_PAPERSIZE-'a4'\}}x /tmp/tmp.LsP3FSBIRI
+ ucf --debug=3 /tmp/tmp.LsP3FSBIRI /etc/R/Renviron
The new start file is      `/tmp/tmp.LsP3FSBIRI\'
The destination is         `/etc/R/Renviron\' (`\/etc\/R\/Renviron\')
The history is kept under  \'/tmp\'
The file may be cached at \'/var/lib/ucf/cache/:etc:R:Renviron\'
The destination file does not exist.
The old md5sum does not exist.
The new file exists, and has md5sum:
7c899e0d9d42df33d5dfd303ef43c46b  /tmp/tmp.LsP3FSBIRI
Historical md5sums are not available
The new start file is      `/tmp/tmp.LsP3FSBIRI\'
The destination is         `/etc/R/Renviron\' (`\/etc\/R\/Renviron\')
The history is kept under  \'/tmp\'
The file may be cached at \'/var/lib/ucf/cache/:etc:R:Renviron\'
dpkg: error processing package r-base-core (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 20
```

Comment: Can you add the result of `ls -l /etc/R` please? By simply removing the postinst file, you've probably ended up without an appropriate R environment.

Comment: Added the result to the question.

Comment: I think you really should try to find out *why* the script is failing - rather than simply suppressing it

Comment: I absolutely agree. This was only a desperate attempt and I was hoping that something non-essential fails. I have no idea of post-installation scripts though and if I google `exit error 10` I'm stuck because there doesn't seem to be anything of use.

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is adding the `-x` shell option (e.g. `set -e -x`) to the postinst script - hopefully that will let you see *where* it fails

Comment: That was probably a great idea. I added the output and as you can see something ucf-related fails. Don't know what to do about that. Is there any way to find out why ucf fails in that line?

Comment: Hmm... ucf is kinda new, I don't have any experience with it - sorry